# How often should I send an invoice?

Tags: invoices

How often should I send out an invoice to the client? 
What is standard practice?

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb: One invoice a month.

But it depends on your business model.

**Monthly subscription:**
Invoice monthly of course. Although here you would probably be taking payment in advance.

**One-off job:**
Options here depending on the size of the job.
1- Invoice for deposit. Invoice on completion.
2- Invoice for deposit. Invoice half way through or on milestones. Invoice on completion.

**Ongoing work.**
Options again...
1. Invoice monthly amount
2. Invoice when amount owed reaches a certain limit or a particular length of time has expired.

**Unpaid invoice.**
1. Send reminder after 2 weeks
2. Send payment required now after 4 weeks
3. Send final demand after 6 weeks
4. Send a letter of intent to prosecute after 8 weeks

But I would have to ask why you are in a situation where your client does not expect when he has to pay. You should detail payment dates in your contract/quote and in your terms and conditions you should lay out penalties for late payment. In the UK it is customary to charge bank base rate + 5% interest monthly on late payments. At this rate it is enforceable by debt collection via the small claims or civil courts - as long as you have a signed contract stating all this beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Send an invoice when payment is due. It's that simple.

Doesn't matter if it's daily, weekly, monthly.. whenever money is due.